# Using where clause to select minimum value in Select_analysis tool of ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, sql, select

I am trying to use the Select_analysis tool to select the minimum value from the input geodatabase feature class and export that to a new feature class via a where clause.  I think I'm getting tripped up on the SQL syntax.

Relevant code:

```
sql = "SELECT MIN([FIELD]) FROM FC" 

arcpy.Select_analysis(input, output, sql)
```

My input and output are defined path variables elsewhere in the code.

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] the question to specify the type of geodstabase, and if enterprise, which RDBMS. Complete details in the body of the question aids in answer generation.

Comment: What happens when you try to run the code that you have presented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first the exception is that this form of select statement does only work on database formats. If you have a shapefile it will not work at all. The syntax you need here is a bit different as in the select by attributes ArcMap needs a subquery for min(). The following should work. The delimiters in ArcMap depend on the format as well. You might need to use other than " around your field names(" is for FileGeodatabase).

```
sql = """"your_field" = (SELECT MIN( "your_field" ) from "your_table")"""
```